# RegEx pattern not matching php, but in c# / java / etc

Tags: java, php, regex

I have a problem with regular expressions in php.

Got the following pattern: `^\s*(\d{8})\s+(.+?)\s+(\d+,\d{2})\s.?\s(.*)$`

My search string is like: 
[image: search string example]
    12345678    This is a little Product Description with some special characters like ®    16,00 €  maybe some text here

I use this php code:

```
$regex = '/^\s*(\d{8})\s+(.+?)\s+(\d+,\d{2})\s.?\s(.*)$/';
echo preg_match($regex, $input);
```

But there is no match!

The same regex pattern in java or c# works! Can you explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Here some online regex tester:

PHP: http://regexp-evaluator.de/evaluator/d721ca1ed32d76db960262ba7298cff3/#ergebnis

Java: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: Can you post the actual search string text instead of a picture of it?

Comment: Yes, but stackoverflow trims the input, and there are some whitespaces at beginning and ending of the string.

Comment: if you consult the [editing help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) or the [formatting reference provided while editing your question](http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0120a86e29f4970b-pi) you'll be able to prevent that.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the `/u` modifier.

After looking for the price value 0,00 your regex compares for a single character `(.?)` between spaces. But the Euro sign `€` usually occupies two bytes. This will only work in UTF-8 mode.

Comment: `$regex = '/^\s*(\d{8})\s+(.+?)\s+(\d+,\d{2})\s.?\s(.*)$/u';` - works! +1

Answer (score 0):

if not in multiline mode, the $ only matches the end of the complete string. If there is a newline-character or more data in $input, this may be the cause. In that case, simply put an "m" behind the final delimiter.

Further I wonder if (.+?) is correct. Have your tried (.*) instead?

BurninLeo

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I'm searching for only single lines, because in front of this code snippet I split the input by \n character. The group (.+?) is correct, because I don't want whitespaces at the end, so I taked the nongreedy mode.